# Spring @Configuration not overriden in test context

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Today I updated my project from Spring Boot 1.5.9 to 2.1.1, and some of my tests stopped working. When i start the tests, error pops on console:

> Field authEntryPoint in com.example.rest.config.SecurityConfig required a bean of type 'com.example.rest.service.auth.entrypoints.AuthenticationEntryPoint' that could not be found.

The problem is I have bean of this type defined in my SecurityConfig class, but I am overriding this configuration in my test package in TestApplication class. Security config is defined there as static inner class. I have tried different approaches including Spring profiles and @Primary annotation, but nothing seems to work and Spring doesn't pick my test configuration like it did before. Only thing that worked was when I deleted the non-test version of SecurityConfig class and test version became only bean of this type.

Can someone tell me how do I override this original configuration or how to turn off Spring Security just for testing? Or maybe there is a way to force Spring not to pick up that non-test @Configuration bean?

**SecurityConfig.class**

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

        @Autowired
        BasicAuthenticationProvider basicAuthProvider;

        @Autowired
        PreAuthenticatedUserDetailsService preAuthUserDetailsService;

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/rest/query/id/*/user/*",
                            "/rest/files/**/*").hasAnyRole("CLIENT", "SYSTEM")
                    .antMatchers("/public/api/management/**/*").hasRole("SYSTEM")
                    .antMatchers("/public/api/**/*").hasAnyRole("SYSTEM", "USER")
                    .antMatchers("/rest/**/*").hasRole("SYSTEM")
                    .and()
                .x509()
                    .userDetailsService(preAuthUserDetailsService)
                    .and()
                .httpBasic()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and().csrf().disable();
        }

        @Autowired
        public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {       
            auth.authenticationProvider(basicAuthProvider);     
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/").antMatchers("/rest/files/name/**");
        }
    }
```

**Test SpringBootClass with SecurityConfig inside**

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestApplication {

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public static class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .and().csrf().disable();
    }
}
```

}

**Example test from the suite**

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(DocumentManagementController.class)
public class DocumentManagementControllerTests {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    SystemMetadataService systemMetadataService;

    @MockBean
    CustomMetadataService customMetadataService;

    @MockBean
    PrinterService printerService;

    @MockBean
    EventLoggerService eventLoggerService;

    @Captor ArgumentCaptor<String> systemCaptor;
    @Captor ArgumentCaptor<String> clientCaptor;
    @Captor ArgumentCaptor<Boolean> holdCaptor;
    @Captor ArgumentCaptor<String> retentionCaptor;
    @Captor ArgumentCaptor<String> objectPathCaptor;
    @Captor ArgumentCaptor<Boolean> accessCaptor;
    @Captor ArgumentCaptor<Boolean> manualProcessingCaptor;
    @Captor ArgumentCaptor<Boolean> incorrectCaptor;
    @Captor ArgumentCaptor<Integer> statusCaptor;
    @Captor ArgumentCaptor<Boolean> noTemplateCaptor;

    @Test
    public void setDocumentAccess_givenProperData_shouldReturnOk() throws Exception {
        when(customMetadataService.setDocumentAccess(anyString(), anyBoolean()))
        .then(inv -> new HcpCreateObjectResult(inv.getArgument(0)));

        Boolean accessForbidden = true; String objectPath = "path";

        mvc.perform(get("/rest/management/access/forbid/"+accessForbidden+"?objectPath="+objectPath))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

        verify(customMetadataService).setDocumentAccess(objectPathCaptor.capture(), accessCaptor.capture());
        assertThat(objectPathCaptor.getValue(), is(equalTo(objectPath)));
        assertThat(accessCaptor.getValue(), is(equalTo(accessForbidden)));
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried put `@TestConfiguration` on your inner class? And why did you put `@SpringBootApplication` on test class?

Comment: Yes i've tried `@TestConfiguration` and effect is the same: `UnsatisfiedDependencyException`. I can put `@SpringBootConfiguration` instead of `@SpringBootApplication`, to configure context and no more `UnsatisfiedDependencyException` is thrown, but then every request returns 404(like the method doesnt exists). It was working perfectly well in earlier version of spring boot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do make this work using `@Profile` and `@ActiveProfiles`. But i had to extract my static inner `@Configuration` class to another java file and then it automagically started to work. Still haven't found why it worked in earlier version of Spring Boot